# Directive/Component name 'ng ' is invalid. The name should not contain leading or trailing whitespaces

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Trying to run my app in production
And get a strange error

**CODE/ERROR MESSAGE**

```
angular.js:68Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ng due to:
Error: [$compile:baddir] Directive/Component name 'ng ' is invalid. The name should not contain leading or trailing whitespaces
```

I looked module with `"ng "` but not found

Is something familiar with the problem?

run on . node 6.2.2 from my Docker file

thanks a lot

Comment: Sounds (and looks) like you have a trailing whitespace in that 'ng '.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is answered but I want to add an extra point. Even though you didn't have any whitespace in your component/Directive name it might throw the same exceptions in case of when your component/directive name starts with a Capital Alphabet. You should always use small case to write the component/Directive name. In your example it should be '**ng**' and not '**ng** ' or '**Ng**'.

For more details please refer [docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.5/docs/error/$compile/baddir)